# if localStorage key value doesn't exist

Tags: html, local-storage

I am trying to hide my div if there is no a localStorage key value.

With the line below I achieved only to hide a div when localStorage key completely deleted but need to do the same if localStorage **key hasn't got any value** at all just [].

```
 window.localStorage.getItem('items') === null
```

How would it be performed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add required conditions using the `OR` operator `||`

```
var items = window.localStorage.getItem('items')

if (items === null || items.length === 0)
{
    // items is null, [] or '' (empty string)
}
```

If you have to check for `undefined` somewhere as well you can change `=== null` to `== null` or expand with an extra condition like this

```
if (items === undefined || items === null || items.length === 0)
{
    // items is undefined, null, [] or '' (empty string)
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is what you can do to get the array directly

```
var items = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('items'))

if (items === null || items.length === 0)
{
    // items is null or []
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ma3x but it doesn't work when [] in a value field, maybe it accepts [] as characters?

Comment: Yep I think I have fixed it with

if (items === undefined || items === null || items.length < 3)

Comment: @qqruza: if you have the array encoded as a JSON string then you can compare like this `items == '[]'` or parse first with `var itemsArray = JSON.parse(items)` and then use `itemsArray.length === 0`.

Comment: @PRMan: Do you mean `if(!items)` since OP wanted to know when there is no array or when the array is empty? The difference is with an empty array, which would not satisfy the `if(!items)` condition.

Answer (score 4):

How about simply:

```
if (!localStorage.nameOfYourLocalStorage) {
    // do the following if the localStorage.nameOfYourLocalStorage does not exist
}
```

An example of how it could be useful:

```
if (!localStorage.nameOfYourLocalStorage) {
    localStorage.nameOfYourLocalStorage = defaultValue;
}
```

Here the script will check if the localStorage name does not exist, and if it doesn't, it will create it with the default value.

And if you want it to act when it *does* exist, you can add an *else* after the if block to continue, or remove the '**!**' from the *if block* condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
Storage.prototype.has = function(key) {
  return (key in this && !(key in Storage.prototype));
};
```